What's the typical circuit for a dimmable LED light bulb?
Most common household dimmers work with old incandescent lights. They seem to use a TRIAC to "cut" some parts of the AC waveform and thus inject less power to the resistance. It is not too different from PWM, but works with AC.
Modern LED light bulbs work with DC voltages due to the nature of LEDs. They usually ship a full rectifier and a couple of capacitors to generate DC from the AC input. With these light bulbs it is not possible to dim the LEDs by using a traditional dimmer (since cutting the AC input does little to the DC output).
However some LED bulbs are "dimmable" (and advertised as such). I assume they must perform some sort of PWM dimming on their output. However the part I am most curious about is: how do they exactly figure out the dimming point based on the AC input? I did not find any circuits or ICs that do this out there. Any ideas?

Dimmable bulbs use a driver IC that measures the phase cut angle on the mains voltage and adjusts the current set point being regulated to the diodes accordingly:

From: https://electronicsmaker.com/controller%20ic%20for%20dimmable%20led%20lighting
Note that the DET pin samples the rectified voltage before the capacitor so that it can measure the phase cut angle. This is then used to modulate the current control loop.

I do not understand why the output is exponentially shaped though. At cut angle 90° wouldnt the output be 50%?

Human vision has an approximately logarithmic sensitivity, so the knob should be roughly exponential to appear that it is uniformly decreasing with angle. If it were linear it would be very sensitive at the low brightness end, from the point of view of the user.
See gamma correction for the general concept.

Do you happen to know what’s different about the dimmers advertised for CFL/LED compatibility which make them work better with dimmable LEDs?

Those are reverse phase angle, meaning the cut starts at 180 degrees and decreases. This avoids the capacitor current spike from the mains voltage suddenly jumping from zero to a high voltage. Instead the discontinuity will be at high to zero voltage, which is fine since the capacitor will discharge into the load.

Do you happen to know what’s different about the dimmers advertised for CFL/LED compatibility which make them work better with dimmable LEDs?

Thank you! That makes a lot of sense and seems simple enough. I do not understand why the output is exponentially shaped though. At cut angle 90° wouldnt the output be 50%? I expected a cosine shaped transformation. Im als not sure what the relationship between phase cut and output brightness looks like for incandescent lights.
